# Mapping response from POST without nested KVC

Tags: json, restkit-0.20

I am trying to map attributes to a class in RESTKit without a nested KVC and without much luck i keep getting nil for my values even though the response contains values.

I have read over the object mapping manual and tried it with path patterns without path patterns etc. Does anyone have any insight?

## Request and Response from server

```
2014-06-16 15:58:07.162 game[5961:60b] T 

restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:178 POST 'https://api.myURL.com/api/0_0_1/notify/player':
request.headers=
{
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    "User-Agent" = "game/1470 (iPhone; iOS 7.1; Scale/2.00)";
}
request.body=
{
    "game":"539e75acadae8fb03900057e",
    "to":"533bd7eb5317b88f61000006",
    "message":"‎Ben Fowler is waiting for you to play the game",
    "from":"5332b4f5edfc9beb7900004d"
}
2014-06-16 15:58:08.856 game[5961:5607] T restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:248 POST 'https://api.myURL.com/api/0_0_1/notify/player' (200 OK / 1 objects) [request=1.6911s mapping=0.0020s total=1.6989s]:
        response.headers={
            Connection = "keep-alive";
            "Content-Length" = 42;
            "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            Date = "Mon, 16 Jun 2014 07:58:09 GMT";
            "X-Powered-By" = Express;
        }
        response.body=
        {
          "result": 1,
          "notify": "871720292"
        }
```

## The class being mapped

```
-(void)WtfGameNotifcationResponse
{
RKObjectMapping *notifyMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[WTFGameNotification class]];

[notifyMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
 @{
 @"result" : @"result",
 @"notify" : @"notifyID",
 }];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:notifyMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                   pathPattern:@"notify/player"
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

}

## The class in question

```
@interface WTFGameNotification : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* to;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* from;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* gameID;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* message;

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber* result;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *notifyID;

+ (WTFGameNotification*)Create;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you are trying to map a response from a POST this is the method and syntax one should use.

```
+ ( void )SendNotification:(GameInfo*)gameInfo withMessage:(NSString*)message forView:(UIViewController*)view
{
    WTFGameNotification *_wtfGameNotif = [WTFGameNotification Create];

    [_wtfGameNotif setTo:[gameInfo opponentWTFID]];
    [_wtfGameNotif setFrom:[PlayerWTFInfo Load]._wtfID];
    [_wtfGameNotif setGameID:[gameInfo gameID]];
    [_wtfGameNotif setMessage:message];

    if ([_wtfGameNotif to] && [_wtfGameNotif gameID])
    {
        RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:_wtfGameNotif
                                                                                                                    method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                                                      path:nil
                                                                                                                parameters:nil];
        RFResponse *r1 = [RFResponse new];
        operation.targetObject = r1;

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
        {
            if (r1.result.integerValue != 0)
            {
                [Utilities FacebookPostWithResult:@{@"fbId": r1.notify}];
            }
        }
        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
        {
            DDLogError(@"POST REQUEST FAILED IN CONFIRMFOTOVC : %@",[error description]);

             if (view)
             {
                 [LoadingView PopToRootShutterCloseOnView:view willOpen:YES];
             }
        }];

        [operation start];

    }
    else
    {
        DDLogInfo(@"NO PLAYER ID");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are POSTing the object to the server then the response descriptor you have will not match because you link it to a GET with `method:RKRequestMethodGET`. You need to change that to `method:RKRequestMethodPOST`.

When using a path pattern of `@"notify/player"` the base URL should be set to `https://api.myURL.com/api/0_0_1/`, but it doesn't look like this is an issue for you.